# warning adding methods into app delegate for core-data

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I have created a new project using core data then copied all of the app delegate code for core-data that I need over into my current projects app delegate..

my appdelegate.m looks like this now.

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  testingcoredata
//
//  Created by iMac on 18/11/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "MasterViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    masterViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error])
        {
            /*
             Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

             abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        } 
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

/**
 Returns the managed object context for the application.
 If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

/**
 Returns the managed object model for the application.
 If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
 */
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"testingcoredata" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

/**
 Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
 If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
 */
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"testingcoredata.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])
    {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter: 
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }    

    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

My questions are as follows
Is the **URLForResource** in this part of the code ment to reflect the name of my xcdatamodeld that I have created?

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"testingcoredata" withExtension:@"momd"];
```

With the **URLByAppendingPathComponent:** do I have to create a sqlite database called Code.sqlite or is this made automatically for me by the core-data code?

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Code.sqlite"];
```

what is the purpose of this method exactly?

```
applicationDocumentsDirectory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **URLForResource** represents the uri path to the momd file in the bundle.
2. **URLByAppendingPathComponent** - code you provided will create database named Code.sqlite. You can freely change the name to whatever you want.
3. **applicationDocumentsDirectory** method returns path to the Documents folder in the app sandbox

Comment: alright. perfect, thanks for that.. so basicly URLByAppendingPathComponent creates the database based off the xcdatamodeld entities I created. (i.e. tables etc.)

Comment: No, that line creates a URL.  The entire stack (`NSManagedObjectModel`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, `NSManagedObjectContext`) would be your "database" that you are thinking of.  However, it is better to think of Core Data as an object graph that *can* persist to a database instead of *just* a database.